# Format from normal numbers to time in [hh]:mm format

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, sql-server-2000, excel-2007

I usually have this nice way in **Excel** to convert normal number format to hour and minutes format using simple cell custom formatting **[HH]:mm** which turns out like this:

[image: excel sheet]

Now I can't seem to find a similar to do this in visual basic 2010 or in sql 2000 so does any one know of a way to do it.
Thanks in advance.

**Note:** the brackets in **[** HH **]**:mm are to keep the hours figure from rounding to 0 after every 24 hour lap.

Comment: You know this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: What do you mean by a "normal number"? I have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Function FormatHoursAndMinutes(totalMinutes As Integer) As String
    Dim span As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(totalMinutes)
    Return String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", CInt(Math.Floor(span.TotalHours)), span.Minutes)
End Function
```

Comment: Yeah thanks I tried it but it's not working properly u know when I write that my time is 1.5 HOURS what I need is to the this result 1:30 while your function gave me another result, I appreciate the direct way of giving an answer though much appreciated.

Comment: Oops.  Forgot to make it round down.  I fixed it by adding the `Math.Floor`.

Comment: It's great thank you, although it's not working when the value is over 24 hours it just rounds back to zero, i.e. 24.5 hours = 00:30 using your function.

Comment: When I pass 1470 into that method, it returns "24.5" for me.  Maybe you typed something wrong?  I suspect you have `span.Hours` instead of `span.TotalHours`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) and to construct it using the [FromMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromminutes.aspx) method.

You can then format the `TimeSpan` for display using `.ToString()` or one of its overloads.

Comment: It doesn't look like any of the standard or custom format strings support that format. So, short of passing in your own formatted object, the ToString method won't work well.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to display hours over 24. Is there a real need in creating a TimeSpan object each time you want to turn Interger to hh:mm?

```
Public Function MinutesTohhmm(ByVal mins As Integer) As String

    Dim hrs As Integer = mins \ 60
    Dim mnts As Integer = mins Mod 60

    Dim hhmmStr As String = IIF(hrs < 10, "0", "") & hrs & ":" & IIF(mnts < 10, "0", "") & mnts

    Return hhmmStr 

End Function
```